# TYPO3 Change Domain

Tags: typo3

I'm new to TYPO3 and I'm trying to bail someone out. They had to shut down their site because of a domain name issue and I'm trying to temporarily resurrect it on my VPS.

This question seemed to be what I needed, but it doesn't seem to correspond to my version:

[Typo3 : using typoscript to modify the base-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188883/typo3-using-typoscript-to-modify-the-base-url)

The only place in the backend that I see Template is in Web->Template. I do see the constant editor here, but no Home. Only root below the name of the site. The second drop-down has Content, Advanced, Plugin..., etc and I don't see any uri options. I've changed the entries in class.tslib_fe.php (both $baseURL and $absRefPrefix) and I was able to break the page, but I don't know how to do it properly. Any tips?

EDIT:

I'm seeing the value in:

Web->Template->root->Template Analyzer->Setup, but I don't know how to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop that `config.baseURL` and replace it with `config.absRefPrefix = /` (or, if you're e.g. in a subdirectory called "foo", it would be `config.absRefPrefix = /foo/`.

This is the domain-aware, non-html-`<base>`-tag way. For more information about this, have a look at http://buzz.typo3.org/people/soeren-malling/article/baseurl-is-dead-long-live-absrefprefix/

> I've changed the entries in class.tslib_fe.php

You don't have to monkeypatch anything in core classes, since this would get overriden in an update.

Besides, if you're using realurl, you may need to adapt `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php` since the domain may be hardcoded in there. Additionally, if on a multidomain-setup, check your domain records (select the topmost item in your page tree with the `List`-module to see possible records).